# How to preserve animation between route changes in gatsby

Tags: reactjs, css-animations, gatsby

I have a Gatsby app with a nav bar at the top. It has a title and a button which opens and closes a menu that has links to different routes.
When the menu opens there's little CSS animation: it slides from left 0 to the right and takes the full screen.
When the menu closes, same thing, slides back to the left and disappears.

Clicking on the title will change route to root route: "/" and close the menu if its open
Clicking on a link in the menu will lead to that route "/other-route" and close the menu

**Effect that I want:** When changing route with the menu open, the menu will still go through the closing animation even if the page behind has changed, kind of revealing the new page.

I've recreated a simple app as an example so you can see the animation and this effect that I like here:

[Example of my app](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/gatsby-menu-animation-zpyrny?file=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FMenu.js)

(In the example, the first time you click on the menu button, there might be an error / the menu won't open, but if you click again it will work normally... this doesn't happen on my app so i didn't try to fix it as it's probably caused by codeSandbox (menu isn't loaded before it's opened))

My opening and closing animations are pure css, and applied to the #menu via js by adding a class "openMenu" or "closeMenu".

**The problem:** To get this effect (on route change the closeMenu animation still finishes), I need to have the class "closeMenu" on the nav component at #menu id by default so that when the new page renders, the Menu component already has the class "closeMenu", which triggers the close animation when the route changes.

=> But this also means that the closeMenu animation will happen even if the menu was not open before: aka on every page render...

If i remove the "closeMenu" class from #menu, the animation runs on open and close via the button, but on route change, the menu just disappears.

So, here's the question, what is the best way to get this closeMenu animation to happen only when the menu was open on route change..?

**What I've tried so far:** I've tried so many things I'm probably forgetting some but none work, so I'm open to new ideas.

- useMemo to have the component not re-render on route change and preserve the animation (couldn't make it work)
- dynamically changing the className, but the rerender will cause the component to reload with its base attributes...
- having a isClose state preserved with useContext.. but that's not really what's needed there
- using in gatsby-browser.js the onRouteChange() hook, to no avail.
- Try to detect from what component was the route change initiated from...
- Maybe onPreRouteChange() could be used to check the state of isClose, and if false (menu is open) add the class "closeMenu" to the Menu Component before its rendered?
- [This approach could work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61274365/allow-component-to-detect-route-change-in-gatsby) not sure how though

Any ideas how to make this works?

Answer (score 0):

I made it work before someone could answer, but in case someone is interested to know how:

In my example, I had a state of isClose which determined if the menu was open or closed.

```
const [isClose, setIsClose] = useState(true);
```

I changed that state from being a *boolean* to being an enum of 3 possible string: "default", "closeMenu", "openMenu".

I wrapped this new state in a context provider so that the state of isClose is shared to the components that i want (without having to pass it as props)

```
    // ./context.js

    enum isCloseEnum {
      isClose = "closeMenu",
      isOpen = "openMenu",
      isDefault = "default",
    }
      
    export const InitialRenderContext = createContext({
        isClose: isCloseEnum.isDefault,
        setIsClose: () => {},
    });
            
    export const InitialRenderProvider = ({ children }) => {
        const [isClose, setIsClose] = useState(isCloseEnum.isDefault);
        
        return (
            <InitialRenderContext.Provider value={{ isClose, setIsClose }}>
            {children}
            </InitialRenderContext.Provider>
        );
    };
```

Now I can use this isClose state in the Menu component and the state is preserved between renders.
By default #menu has a class of "default" which does nothing and could be refactor :p, when the button is clicked, the menu opens, and the class "openMenu" applied to #menu. Similarly, on pressing closing button, isClose changes states, so #menu now has "closeMenu" class.

Now if the menu is opened and you change route, the state is preserved, so the class "closeMenu" is preserved on the Component so the animation happens even on rerender

Finally, when isClose state is === "closeMenu" an event listener waits for the end of the animation, and proceeds to setIsClose state back to default.

Like this when switching between pages normally, we have normal page transition, but the animation is preserved if menu is open, gg.

```
// ./Menu.js

export const Menu = ({ closeMenu }) => {
  const { isClose, setIsClose } = useContext(InitialRenderContext);
  const menu = document.getElementById("menu");

  if (isClose === "closeMenu") {
    menu.addEventListener("animationend", () => {
      if (menu.classList.contains("closeMenu")) {
        menu.classList.remove("closeMenu");
        setIsClose(isCloseEnum.isDefault);
      }
      return () => menu?.removeEventListener("animationend", () => {});
    });
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div id="menu" className={isClose}>
    </>
  )
}
```